# How do you add a condition to a generator function based on the previous output?

Tags: python, string, iteration, generator, tokenize

I am trying to reconcile `id_label_token`, which is a list of tuples containing a tokenized string, label, and character index, with the original string `string`.

I have some working code that uses a generator to do this. However, it can't handle instances where there is a label for a token between parentheses in the original string. I am new to generators, and I am finding it difficult to implement a condition that produces my desired output.

How could I check the previous `token_type` against the current `token_type` so that I don't skip assigning a `token_type` when a token is between parentheses?

Some help would be appreciated. And if this question requires different framing, please don't hesitate to say so.

Data:

```
id_label_token = [(0, 'O', '('),
                  (1, 'DATE-B', '6'),
                  (2, 'DATE-I', ')'),
                  (4, 'DATE-I', '13th'),
                  (9, 'DATE-B', 'February'),
                  (18, 'DATE-I', '1942'),
                  (23, 'O', '('),
                  (24, 'GPE-B', 'N.S.'),
                  (28, 'O', ')')]

string = "(6) 13th February 1942 (N.S.)"
```

Current code:

```
def get_tokens(tokens):
    it = iter(tokens)
    _, token_type, next_token = next(it)
    word = yield
    while True:
        if next_token == word:
            word = yield next_token, token_type
            _, token_type, next_token = next(it)
        else:
            _, _, tmp = next(it)
            next_token += tmp

it = get_tokens(id_label_token)
next(it)
out = [it.send(w) for w in string.split()]
print(out)
```

Current output:

```
[('(6)', 'O'), ('13th', 'DATE-I'), ('February', 'DATE-B'), ('1942', 'DATE-I'), ('(N.S.)', 'O')]
```

Desired output:

```
[('(6)', 'DATE-B'), ('13th', 'DATE-I'), ('February', 'DATE-B'), ('1942', 'DATE-I'), ('(N.S.)', 'GPE-B')]
```

Comment: Could `id_label_token` contain 2 or more consecutive `(` tokens (last subitem) in consecutive tuples? Should `id_label_token` always represent a valid tokenized string?

Comment: i. Do you mean could there be instances of consecutive `)` or `(` as individual tokens and/or instances of parentheses as individual tokens surrounding a token that already has parentheses? No. ii. Valid by what measure? The data in `id_label_token` has been processed by spaCy. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Though there can also be instances of consecutive tuples that include other punctuation, such that the consecutive tokens would be `(` `N.S.` `)` `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update `next_token`, you should also update `token_type` when you reach the 'heart' of the parentheses; you only have to check whether you've reached the closing `)` (or rather whether you've NOT reached it):

```
def get_tokens(tokens):
    it = iter(tokens)
    _, token_type, next_token = next(it)
    word = yield
    while True:
        if next_token == word:
            word = yield next_token, token_type
            _, token_type, next_token = next(it)
        else:
            _, new_tt, tmp = next(it)
            next_token += tmp
            if tmp != ')':
                token_type = new_tt
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really readable. If you don't mind me asking further, how could you handle a situation where the consecutive tokens were `(` `N.S.` `)` `,`, which should return `('(N.S.),', 'GPE-B')`?

Comment: Hello: I think it would be enough to replace `tmp != ')'` with `tmp not in (')', ',')` . You want to "ignore" (in terms of updating token_type) whatever comes after the "heart" of the element.

Comment: Right, I get it now. How you were getting this (correct) output `('(3', 'DATE-B'), ('and', 'DATE-I'), ('7)', 'DATE-I'),` was confusing me. The code I provided was yielding `('(3', 'O'), ('and', 'DATE-I'), ('7)', 'DATE-I'),` for example. Truly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As the main complexity is in recognizing parenthesized tokens (among adjacent items) use the following *generator* approach:

```
def get_tokens(labels, t_str):
    labels_it = iter(labels)
    tokens = iter(t_str.split())

    for _, lbl, t in labels_it:
        inp_t = next(tokens)  # token from the input string
        if t == '(':
            (_, lbl, val), right_p = next(labels_it), next(labels_it)[-1]
            t = t + val + right_p  # parenthesized token
        if inp_t == t:
            yield t, lbl

t_string = "(6) 13th February 1942 (N.S.)"
out = list(get_tokens(id_label_token, t_string))
print(out)
```

---

```
[('(6)', 'DATE-B'), ('13th', 'DATE-I'), ('February', 'DATE-B'), ('1942', 'DATE-I'), ('(N.S.)', 'GPE-B')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I like that this addresses the problem singularly. However, I am having trouble running it on further examples. For example, take `id_label_token = [(0, 'O', '1'),(1, 'O', '.'),(3, 'ORG-B', 'Mark'),(10, 'O', 'Johnson'),(18, 'O', 'TO'),(21, 'PERSON-B', 'Mark'),(26, 'PERSON-I', 'Johnson')]` and `t_string = '1. Mark Johnson TO Mark Johnson'`. I'm not quite sure why the generator now raises a `StopIteration`.

Comment: @doine, what should be the result for that new input? And what label should be taken if `t_string` starts with `1.2 ...` having the respective tuples `(0, 'O', '1'),(1, 'O', '.'),(3, 'ORG-B', '1')` ?

Comment: @doine: the StopIteration probably comes from `1.` being 1 item in the split string, but 2 in the tokenized iterator, resulting in a difference in length between the two iterators.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i. Forgive me, I garbled my previous comment. Should be: `id_label_token = [(0, 'O', '1'),(1, 'O', '.'),(3, 'PERSON-B', 'Mark'),(10, 'PERSON-I', 'Johnson'),(18, 'O', 'TO'),(21, 'PERSON-B', 'Mark'),(26, 'PERSON-I', 'Johnson')]` `t_string = '1. Mark Johnson TO Mark Johnson'` >>>`[('1.', 'O'), ('Mark', 'PERSON-B'), ('Johnson', 'PERSON-I'), ('TO', 'DATE-I'), ('Mark', 'PERSON-B'), ('Johnson', 'PERSON-I')]` ii. I can confirm that I don't have an instance of this in my dataset. The tuples you give would only be rendered from `'1. 2 ...` (i.e. there's whitespace between `.` and `2`)

Comment: @doine, I meant: could `t_string` contain a float number like `1.2` (without whitespace) ?

Comment: Mid-string, yes, there could be an instance of a float. Apologies, I thought you meant the start of strings only.

Comment: @doine, if so what  label should be taken for `1.2` from the respective tuples `(0, 'O', '1'),(1, 'O', '.'),(3, 'ORG-B', '2')` ?

Comment: I suppose I would want to take `ORG-B`, but I'm not sure it aligns with a real example in my data. I'm using spaCy and if `text = "It's 4.25. 4.25 per cent. $4.25."` then `id_label_token = [(0, 'O', 'It'), (2, 'O', "'s"), (5, 'CARDINAL-B', '4.25'), (9, 'O', '.'), (11, 'MONEY-B', '4.25'), (16, 'MONEY-I', 'per'), (20, 'MONEY-I', 'cent'), (24, 'O', '.'), (26, 'O', '$'), (27, 'MONEY-B', '4.25'), (31, 'O', '.')]`